# Mouse freezing after copying and pasting

Tags: mouse, freeze

My Mouse freezes anytime in Ubuntu, hover still works but I can't click anything.

Keyboard Works and I have to press Windows Key to open dock and everything works again.

It happens frequently and only thing that solves it is the windows key. I am a Beginner and haven't tried any Solutions yet.

Mouse - Cosmic Byte Keyboard - Tvs Gold

```
uname -a

Linux dhruv-ubuntu 6.5.0-21-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Feb  7 14:17:40 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 23.10
Release:    23.10
Codename:   mantic

```
lsusb 
        
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 256c:006d HUION Huion Tablet_HS64
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04d9:1203 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04d9:a216 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. CB Gaming Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Recently Discovered that this is happening, when I paste anything after copying.